# Why is EF Core parametrising with incorrect data types?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

I've been playing with .NET 8 RC2 and I have not come across this before in EF Core.

I have created a dynamic query and part of the query is this:

```
_ordersQuery = _ordersQuery.Where(x => !stationIds.Contains(x.StationNo));
```

`stationIds` is of type `List<short>`.

When I do `.ToQueryString()` on the query I notice this:

```
DECLARE @__stationIds_7 nvarchar(4000) = N'[117,116,98]';
```

then in the actual `WHERE` part of the SQL query I see this

```
NOT IN (
   SELECT [s0].[value]
   FROM OPENJSON(@__stationIds_7) WITH ([value] smallint '$') AS [s0]
```

Why is it being treated as JSON?

Comment: Don't assume this is wrong. The value isn't treated as JSON, it's treated as a *JSON array* passed as a parameter, instead of a hard-coded `NOT IN (....)` clause. I'd bet that if you compare `NOT IN (...)` with this query you won't find performance differences.

Comment: "xml shredding" and now "json shredding" .. an xml-input or json-input to hold (many) values... has been "a way" to handle the (many) values for a long time.  (since sql-server-2000-OPENXML).   It is just a (different) way to handle many values.

Comment: XML was slow while the JSON functions are *faster* than the XML functions were *even* with XML indexes.

Comment: It might even be faster - the JSON array can be parameterised and thus not break the SQL plan cache whereas an IN clause wouldn't be so easy to manage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a smart idea! The type is definitely not wrong. Instead of generating a hard-coded `IN`, the list is passed as a JSON array, deserialized with OPENJSON (a very fast method) and used with `NOT IN`.

Until now, `list.Contains` or `!list.Contains` were transformed to hard-coded SQL clauses `IN (@id1, @id2, ....)` or `NOT IN (...)`. The number of items had to be known in advance. Now, while the server can take advantage of the statistics of the `IN (...)` clause to calculate how many matches there may be, a `NOT IN (..)` is almost useless. If there are 1M IDs and 100 items in `NOT IN`, the server will still have to scan the entire table for the other 9999000 matching items.

Another concern is that a varying number of parameters in `IN (...)` would result in multiple execution plans, not only filling the cache with single-use plans but evicting other useful plans

This was announced in [EF Core 8 Preview 4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef8-preview-4/), in the *Translating LINQ Contains with a parameter collection* section and addressed a pretty serious performance issue, especially for long-lived web sites (emphasis mine):

> But crucially, the negative performance impact of constantly varying SQLs goes beyond this particular query. SQL Server (and Npgsql) can only cache a certain number of SQLs; at some point, they have to get rid of old entries to avoid using too much memory. If you frequently use Contains with a variable array, **each individual invocation causes valuable cache entries to be taken at the database, for SQLs that will most probably never be used** (since they have the specific array values baked in). That means **you’re also evicting cache entries for other, important SQLs that will need to be used**, and requiring them to be re-planned again and again.

As the docs say, this was [the second highest voted performance issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13617) in the EF Core repo.

Comment: Yes, nice idea, but maybe TVP parameters should be faster, but it requires declaring custom type.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv that's mentioned in the blog post, along with the fact PostgreSQL needs no such tricks because it's the only database with real arrays. Seems like EF is having to handle T-SQL shortcomings, caused by the lack of new language features in the last couple of versions. Many important EF features actually started in NpgSQL

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

This is translation change introduced in EF Core 8 to tackle performance problems in MS SQL Server provider, which had lead to query plan caching problems.

Note that it can break the query execution if you have older SQL Server or compatibility level set for database. In this case for MSSQL you can run:

```sql
SELECT compatibility_level 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name = 'MyDBName';
```

And either upgrade the database or use the value when setting up the `DbContext` options:

```
optionsBuilder
        .UseSqlServer(@"<CONNECTION STRING>", o => o.UseCompatibilityLevel(thValue));
```

**Details**

Checkout breaking changes for EF Core 8, particularly the [Contains in LINQ queries may stop working on older SQL Server versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/breaking-changes#contains-in-linq-queries-may-stop-working-on-older-sql-server-versions):

> **Old behavior**
> Previously, when the Contains operator was used in LINQ queries with a parameterized value list, EF generated SQL that was inefficient but worked on all SQL Server versions.

> **New behavior**
> Starting with EF Core 8.0, EF now generates SQL that is more efficient, but is unsupported on SQL Server 2014 and below.

> Note that newer SQL Server versions may be configured with an older compatibility level, also making them incompatible with the new SQL. This can also occur with an Azure SQL database which was migrated from a previous on-premises SQL Server instance, carrying over the old compatibility level.

And WHY:

> The previous SQL generated by EF Core for Contains inserted the parameterized values as constants in the SQL. For example, the following LINQ query:

```cs
var names = new[] { "Blog1", "Blog2" };

var blogs = await context.Blogs
    .Where(b => names.Contains(b.Name))
    .ToArrayAsync();
```

> would be translated to the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT [b].[Id], [b].[Name]
FROM [Blogs] AS [b]
WHERE [b].[Name] IN (N'Blog1', N'Blog2')
```

> Such insertion of constant values into the SQL creates many performance problems, defeating query plan caching and causing unneeded evictions of other queries. The new EF Core 8.0 translation uses the SQL Server OPENJSON function to instead transfer the values as a JSON array. This solves the performance issues inherent in the previous technique; however, the OPENJSON function is unavailable in SQL Server 2014 and below.

Comment: Thanks for this, can't believe I missed it!

Answer (score 1):

```
NOT IN (
   SELECT [s0].[value]
   FROM OPENJSON(@__stationIds_7) WITH ([value] smallint '$') AS [s0]
```

.NET has made some improvements to its SQL generation, I'm assuming that one of them would be how to handle lookups in lists.

From your post, it looks like it's passing the list of integer values a json list.

"FROM OPENJSON()" is a json parsing function within SQL Server, "WITH ()" instructs sql what the data structure within the json looks like, the '$' points to the root object.

So from the above sql string, it parses the json '[117,116,98]', instructing SQL that the root object (each record within that list) to be of type smallint.

Not sure if this helps :)

Comment: Yep yours and @Panagiotis comment explains things and makes sense. I spotted this investigating a separate issue which I will post a separate question